# Number system where negative numbers are represented as letters

Tags: coordinate-systems, number-systems

Forgive me for a possibly dumb question, I'm very shallow at math, but is there any number system (or I don't know, it looks more like a number *mask* system) in which negative numbers are represented as letters? An example could look like that:

| -12 | -11 | -10 | -f | -e | -d | -c | -b | -a | -9 | -8 | -7 | -6 | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| zy | zz | z0 | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... |

Now, I can't yet imagine how the fractional numbers would look like in such a system, but if only used for integers, is there some decorative value to that? I need that for a coordinate system for an infinite field (or like ever-expanding field)

Comment: Why only negative numbers are represented by letters, and not natural numbers? also why is there $-a$ on the left of $-9$? Other than that, it just looks as if you changed symbols that represent each number, so there wouldn't be any new 'math' behind it. Why do you need such a system?

Comment: Romans had something like that. Then the result : how many Roman mathematicians do you know ? Just a quizz for you : compute $zy \times \frac{m }q+zo$

Comment: @mowzorn it has base of 16, that's why -a. Regarding just changing each number, yeah, that's why I've mentioned that the principle seems to be just masking, I only wondered if this was ever done before. And yes, there's no 'math' behind it, the application is merely decorative

Comment: @mowzorn and the purpose of this is just to visually get rid of negative numbers, that's all